# How to require restart after installation in Installshield Express?

Tags: installshield, restart

How do you make a Installshield Express installation require a restart after installation?

Please note that I am talking about Installshield Express, so referring to specific MSI properties will not answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have `express` installed ( I've only used AdminStudio, Prem. Pro and Limited Editions ) but a google search showed up an old [answer from 2004](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showpost.php?p=221119&postcount=2).

> To add a scheduled reboot:
>    1. Go to the Custom Action View
>    2. Right click on root node and select "Add from Gallery -> Schedule Reboot at End"

Perhaps this is still valid information.

Comment: Would you advise using custom actions?  I would have thought they might require different permissions to the standard part of the MSI, and hence are bit risky to use? see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2007/10/24/exe-custom-actions-are-bad.aspx

Comment: I think this might be a standard action instead of a custom one. However, how else do you think this could be accomplished, outside of actions or properties?

Comment: It seemed to me that you explicitly wanted to know how to do it in InstallShield Express and didn't want any discussion of general MSI reboot handling.   I answered your question as it was framed.  If you suddenly want to ask about EXE custom actions are risky then I'd want to ask why you need to explcitly request a reboot?  Normally the best practice is to let MSI decide if a reboot is needed and to try to avoid them in the first place.